# get point in list furthest away from points in other list

Tags: java

I have a list of players, and a list of spawnpoints. Every player has a character object, and every character has a position. A character has a number of lives, and when killed, he respawns at the spawnpoint furthest away from the other players as long as he has lives left. For this I created the following code:

```
for (Player spawnPlayer : players) {
   if (spawnPlayer.getCharacter().getCanSpawn()) {
      System.out.println("works");
      List<Integer> distanceArrayList = new ArrayList();
      for (Point point : map.getSpawnPoints()) {
         int distance = 0;
         for (Player player : players) {
             if (player != spawnPlayer && player.getCharacter().getLives() > 0 && !player.getCharacter().getCanSpawn()) {
                distance += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point.x - player.getCharacter().getPosition().x, 2)
                                    + Math.pow(point.y - player.getCharacter().getPosition().y, 2));
             }
         }
         distanceArrayList.add(distance);
      }
      Point spawnPoint = map.getSpawnPoints().get(distanceArrayList.indexOf(Collections.max(distanceArrayList)));
                spawnPlayer.getCharacter().spawn(spawnPoint);

   }
}
```

The spawnpoints are hardcoded, at 0,0, 200,0, 0,500 and 200,500. However players don't always go to the furthest spawnpoint (there are only two players and one doesn't move during the tests) and sometimes don't change position at all, even though this method was called.

**EDIT**

So the code we use at this moment is as follows:

```
public void SpawnPlayers()
{
    for (Player spawnPlayer : players)
    {
        if (spawnPlayer.getCharacter().getCanSpawn())
        {
            int maxDistance = 0;
            Point spawnPoint = null;
            for (Point point : map.getSpawnPoints())
            {
                int sumDistancesFromOthers = 0;
                for (Player player : players)
                {
                    if (player != spawnPlayer && player.getCharacter().getLives() > 0 && !player.getCharacter().getCanSpawn())
                    {
                        sumDistancesFromOthers += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point.x - player.getCharacter().getPosition().x, 2)
                                + Math.pow(point.y - player.getCharacter().getPosition().y, 2));
                    }
                }
                if (maxDistance < sumDistancesFromOthers || spawnPoint == null)
                {
                    maxDistance = sumDistancesFromOthers;
                    spawnPoint = point;
                }
            }
            spawnPlayer.getCharacter().spawn(spawnPoint);
        }
    }
}
```

However, the players still sometimes spawn at wrong positions, sometimes don't spawn at a new location at all, and at the start of the match, all players spawn at the same location. The method SpawnPlayers() gets called every time the game updates, and the boolean canSpawn gets correctly updated when a player dies.

The spawn method:

```
public void spawn(Point spawnPoint)
{
    setPosition(spawnPoint);
    canSpawn = false;
    for (Weapon weapon : weapons)
    {
        weapon.restartShotsRemaining();
    }
    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            canBeHit = true;
        }
    }, 1500);
}
```

Comment: It's hard to imagine what could be "THE answer" here. It seems like a very broad and generic question, close to "looking for debugging help". Without knowing the existing classes, it's hard to guess what might be wrong there. So here is it, a guess: Does calling the `spawn` method change the point that is returned in `getPosition()`? If possible, post an MCVE, either by leaving out the methods of the existing classes that are not relevant, or by implementing the algorithm *itself* on more generic "dummy" classes.

Comment: Are you sure that your math is OK? Or is this a programming question?

Comment: I'm unsure about the math and the programming, as I can't see any problems with both but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it's a bit difficult to flesh out what the actual question is. Questions that are looking for debugging help are usually considered as off-topic.

From the information that was provided so far, it's hard to clearly derive the "state space" of the objects that are involved in this computation. For example, the relationship between `getCanSpawn()` and `getLives()>0`. It is not clear when the `canSpawn` flag will be set to `true` or `false`, and when the `lives` count is decreased. The code in the question also does not seem to consider that positions that are already **occupied** by other players should not be used as a spawn position.

As a general recommendation is therefore to break down the algorithm into smaller parts, that are easier to test and debug. For example, looking at the original code:

```
public void SpawnPlayers()
{
    for (Player spawnPlayer : players)
    {
        if (spawnPlayer.getCharacter().getCanSpawn())
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The innermost part lends itself to be extracted into a method like

```
private void spawnPlayer(Player playerToSpawn)
{
    System.out.println("Spawning "+playerToSpawn);
    ...
}
```

which makes it also far easier to understand (and see on the console) *when* a certain player is about to be spawned, and what happens with this player afterwards (as indicated by further `System.out` statements).

Now, there are two things that are relevant for computing the spawn position of a new player:

- The positions that are still available for spawning
- The positions that the other players have (and which consequently are *no* longer available for spawning)

These can be computed as two sets...

```
Set<Point> availableSpawnPoints = ...;
Set<Point> positionsOfOtherPlayers = ...;
```

The contents of these sets will depend on the `getCanSpawn()` and `getLives()` values, and may have to be adjusted according to your needs and the interplay of these methods.

However, after these sets have been computed, the whole algorithm that you asked for (according to the question title) boils down to a single method - namely a method that receives two sets of points, and computes the point from the first set that is "furthest away" from points in the second set.

There are different possible interpretations of what "furthest away" means. You computed some sum of distances, which looked a bit odd for me. Imagine you have two "fixed" points (the locations of existing players), and a set of "candidate" points (where the player may be spawned), as in this image:

[image: Spawning]

Now, imagine that...

- the distances of A to the others are 3.8 and 0.3, resulting in a sum of 4.1
- the distances of B to the others are 2.0 and 2.0, resulting in a sum of 4.0

Then, with your approach, point A would be chosen as the spawn position. (The same applies in this example when you simply compute the maximum distance of the "candidate" point to any fixed point). But intuitively (and according to the description), you would probably like to **compute the point that has the largest *minimal* distance to any other point**. Or more naturally: The point that is as far away as possible from any other point.

So the computation of the spawn point could probably be done with some method like

```
private Point computePointWithLargestMinimumDistance(
    Iterable<? extends Point> points, Set<? extends Point> others)
{
    ...
}
```

where you can pass in the `availableSpawnPoints` and the `positionsOfOtherPlayers`.

<sub>(BTW: The method signature is in its most generic form. You could also use more specific parameter types, like `HashSet<Point>`, but this is simply not required here - so why not do it generically...)</sub>

This is implemented here, sketching the classes that you mentioned, as far as reasonably possible:

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


public class PlayerSpawning
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        PlayerSpawning p = new PlayerSpawning();
        p.spawnPlayers();
    }

    private List<Player> players;
    private PlayerMap map;

    PlayerSpawning()
    {
        map = new PlayerMap();
        players = new ArrayList<Player>();

        Player player0 = new Player("player0");
        player0.getCharacter().setPosition(new Point(0,0));
        player0.getCharacter().setCanSpawn(false);
        players.add(player0);

        Player player1 = new Player("player1");
        player1.getCharacter().setCanSpawn(true);
        players.add(player1);
    }

    public void spawnPlayers()
    {
        for (Player player : players)
        {
            if (player.getCharacter().getCanSpawn())
            {
                spawnPlayer(player);
            }
        }
    }

    private void spawnPlayer(Player playerToSpawn)
    {
        System.out.println("Spawning "+playerToSpawn);

        Set<Point> availableSpawnPoints = 
            new LinkedHashSet<Point>(map.getSpawnPoints());
        Set<Point> positionsOfOtherPlayers = 
            new LinkedHashSet<Point>();
        for (Player player : players)
        {
            if (player.getCharacter().getLives() <= 0)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (player.getCharacter().getCanSpawn())
            {
                continue;
            }
            Point position = player.getCharacter().getPosition();

            System.out.println(
                "Have to consider that "+player+" is at "+position+
                " - this position is no longer available for spawing!");
            positionsOfOtherPlayers.add(position);
            availableSpawnPoints.remove(position);
        }

        Point spawnPoint = computePointWithLargestMinimumDistance(
            availableSpawnPoints, positionsOfOtherPlayers);

        System.out.println("Spawning "+playerToSpawn+" at "+spawnPoint);
        playerToSpawn.getCharacter().spawn(spawnPoint);
    }


    private Point computePointWithLargestMinimumDistance(
        Iterable<? extends Point> points, Set<? extends Point> others)
    {
        System.out.println("Compute point from    "+points);
        System.out.println("that is furthest from "+others);

        double largestMinDistance = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        Point result = null;
        for (Point point : points)
        {
            double minDistance = 
                computeMinimumDistance(point, others);
            if (minDistance > largestMinDistance)
            {
                largestMinDistance = minDistance;
                result = point;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(
            "The point that has the largest minimum " +
            "distance "+largestMinDistance+" to any other point is "+result);
        return result;
    }


    private double computeMinimumDistance(
        Point point, Iterable<? extends Point> others)
    {
        double minDistanceSquared = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
        for (Point other : others)
        {
            minDistanceSquared = 
                Math.min(minDistanceSquared, point.distanceSq(other));
        }
        return Math.sqrt(minDistanceSquared);
    }

}


class Player
{
    private String name;
    private Character character = new Character();

    public Player(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Character getCharacter()
    {
        return character;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return name;
    }

}
class Character
{
    private Point position = new Point();
    private boolean canSpawn = false;

    public boolean getCanSpawn()
    {
        return canSpawn;
    }

    public void setCanSpawn(boolean canSpawn)
    {
        this.canSpawn = canSpawn;
    }

    public int getLives()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public Point getPosition()
    {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(Point p)
    {
        position.setLocation(p);
    }

    public void spawn(Point spawnPoint)
    {
        setPosition(spawnPoint);
        canSpawn = false;
    }


}

class PlayerMap
{

    public List<Point> getSpawnPoints()
    {
        return Arrays.asList(
            new Point(0,0),
            new Point(200,0),
            new Point(0, 500),
            new Point(200,500));
    }

}
```

The output of this [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, as desired:

```
Spawning player1
Have to consider that player0 is at java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0] - this position is no longer available for spawing!
Compute point from    [java.awt.Point[x=200,y=0], java.awt.Point[x=0,y=500], java.awt.Point[x=200,y=500]]
that is furthest from [java.awt.Point[x=0,y=0]]
The point that has the largest minimum distance 538.5164807134504 to any other point is java.awt.Point[x=200,y=500]
Spawning player1 at java.awt.Point[x=200,y=500]
```

Comment: Just signal me when you feel it's appropriate to upvote your answer. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use local variables to remember the current maximum and corresponding position. You will gain performance by avoiding searching a list. This will change the code as follows:

```
for (Player spawnPlayer : players) {
  if (spawnPlayer.getCharacter().getCanSpawn()) {
    System.out.println("works");
    int maxDistance = 0;
    Point spawnPoint = null;
    for (Point point : map.getSpawnPoints()) {
      int sumDistancesFromOthers = 0;
      for (Player player : players) {
        if (player != spawnPlayer && player.getCharacter().getLives() > 0 && !player.getCharacter().getCanSpawn()) {
          sumDistancesFromOthers += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point.x - player.getCharacter().getPosition().x, 2)
              + Math.pow(point.y - player.getCharacter().getPosition().y, 2));
        }
      }
      if (maxDistance < sumDistancesFromOthers || spawnPoint == null) {
        maxDistance = sumDistancesFromOthers;
        spawnPoint = point;
      }
    }
    spawnPlayer.getCharacter().spawn(spawnPoint);
  }
}
```

I added the test `spawnPoint == null` to make sure `spawnPoint` won't be `null` when you exit the loop.

Hope this will help...

Jeff

------------ UPDATE ------------

I corrected the snippet above to take into consideration the sum of distances from other players as the definition of the distance to be maximized.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. When I am in the bottom left corner (0,0) and I shoot the stationary opponent he spawns at (200,0) instead of (200,500)

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked your definition of the distance to be maximized. Please see my update above.

Answer (score 0):

Proposed code change:

```
for (Player spawnPlayer : players) {
   if (spawnPlayer.getCharacter().getCanSpawn()) {
      System.out.println("works");          
      int maxDistance = 0;
      Point currentSpawnPoint = null;
      for (Point point : map.getSpawnPoints()) {
         int distance = 0;             
         for (Player player : players) {
             if (player != spawnPlayer && player.getCharacter().getLives() > 0 && !player.getCharacter().getCanSpawn()) {
                distance += Math.sqrt(Math.pow(point.x - player.getCharacter().getPosition().x, 2)
                                    + Math.pow(point.y - player.getCharacter().getPosition().y, 2));
             }
         }
         if(distance>maxDistance){
             maxDistance = distance;
             currentSpawnPoint = Point;
         }
      }
    spawnPlayer.getCharacter().spawn(spawnPoint);

   }
}
```

Reasoning: Remembering the distances is not necessary, and reliance on list-indexes is not the way to clean code (They might change).

Comment: Do you ever get an exception? Your logic seems ok , but you have that crazy if statement. It seems quite possible that the distance is never greater than 0 and you get a spawn(null); Perhaps you should change if(distance>=maxDistance).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a problem in your code snippet if the following assumptions are true:

1. `Character.getCanSpawn()` implies `Character.getLives() > 0`
2. `Character.spawn(spawnPoint)` ensures `Character.getCanSpawn() == false` (post condition)

You can initially still get closer-than-optimal spawns: assuming you randomly choose a spawn position for the first character, the second is only optimally placed w.r.t. the first. However there might now be a more optimal position for the first character.

Comment: The characters are all placed at the same spot, not even at different spawn points.

Comment: @DennisvanGils then you have a problem in the above mentioned assumptions: you have to show more of your character class (i.e. the type of `spawnPlayer.getCharacter()`). For example: if assumption 2 is not valid, of course all players will spawn on the same exact spot - you don't consider players with `Character.getCanSpawn() == true` in your distance measure.

Comment: @DennisvanGils you're still showing too few information, as with `canSpawn = false` I assume assumption 2 holds, but do all players start with `getLives() > 0` when they are first spawned (related to assumption 1)?

Answer (score 0):

I was a little bit too lazy to 'debug' your code, that's why I created the snippet of code below.

Anyway,

- I suggest you divide the code into smaller pieces. For example, I would move the code to calculate the distance between two points to the `Point` class.
- Furthermore, your code below,

  ```
  if (maxDistance < sumDistancesFromOthers || spawnPoint == null) {
      maxDistance = sumDistancesFromOthers;
      spawnPoint = point;
  }
  ```

  is a little weird: if *either* `maxDistance < sumDistancesFromOthers` *or* `spawnPoint == null`, then the current spawnpoint is selected. I assume you mean: if either `maxDistance < sumDistancesFromOthers` *and* `spawnPoint == null`...

The code below assumes that at least one player is alive. Then, when spawning all dead players, each spawnpoint is compared to each position of players who are alive. I have set the position to `null` if a player is dead and needs respawning.
This code also assumes that multiple players *can* be at the same spawnpoint. But that happens only if *all spawnpoints* are occupied.

**Player**

```
public class Player {

    private Position position;

    public Player(Position initialPosition) {
        this.position = initialPosition;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a copy of the player's position.
     * @return The player's position.
     */
    public Position getPosition() {
        return new Position(this.position);
    }

    /**
     */
    public SpawnPoint spawn(List<SpawnPoint> spawnPoints, List<Player> players) {
        double highestDistance = 0.0d;
        SpawnPoint bestSpawnPoint = null;
        for (SpawnPoint sp : spawnPoints) {
            double distance = 0.0d;
            for (Player p : players) {
                if (p.isAlive()) {
                    distance += sp.getPosition().getDistance(p.getPosition());
                }
            }
            if (distance > highestDistance) {
                highestDistance = distance;
                bestSpawnPoint = sp;
            }
        }
        if (bestSpawnPoint == null) {
            // Do something if there is no best spawnpoint, that is,
            // when all spawnpoints are occupied and thus the furthest
            // spawnpoint is at a distance of 0.0.
        }
        return bestSpawnPoint;
    }

    public boolean isAlive() {
        return (this.position != null);
    }
}
```

**Position**

```
public class Position {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Position(Position position) {
        if (position != null) {
            this.x = position.x;
            this.y = position.y;
        }
    }

    public Position(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the distance between this position and the given position.
     * @param anotherPosition The position to compare the current position with.
     * @return The distance as a double.
     */
    public double getDistance(Position anotherPosition) {
        double xDistance = Math.abs(Math.pow(this.x - anotherPosition.x, 2));
        double yDistance = Math.abs(Math.pow(this.y - anotherPosition.y, 2));
        return Math.sqrt(xDistance + yDistance);
    }
}
```

**SpawnPoint**

```
public class SpawnPoint {

    private Position position;

    public SpawnPoint(Position position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public SpawnPoint(int x, int y) {
        this(new Position(x, y));
    }

    public Position getPosition() {
        return new Position(this.position);
    }
}
```

And the main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Create some spawnpoints...
    List<SpawnPoint> spawnPoints = new ArrayList<SpawnPoint>() {{
        add(new SpawnPoint(0, 0));
        add(new SpawnPoint(2, 0));
        add(new SpawnPoint(0, 5));
        add(new SpawnPoint(2, 5));
    }};

    // Create some players
    Player playerA = new Player(new Position(0, 0));
    Player playerB = new Player(new Position(4, 1));
    Player playerC = new Player((Position) null);
    // A null position means that the player is dead.

    // Add the players to the list of players...
    List<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>() {{
        add(playerA);
        add(playerB);
        add(playerC);
    }};

    // Spawn playerC (which is currently dead and need to be respawned)
    // and return the best spawn point as defined by the OP
    SpawnPoint sp = playerC.spawn(spawnPoints, players);

    // Print the position
    System.out.println(sp.getPosition());

}
```

I kept it simple, and it works.

Then you can check whether a player is alive and so on by yourself.

*Note: As Marco13 already stated, it would more logical to determine the largest minimum between a spawnpoint and any player. Or you can make an algorithm which tries to take both into account.*